# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in RTEvents.exe

Tags: c#, dll, ado.net, .net-framework-version

I'm using third party dll to integrate zteco biometric device. I've add zkemkeeper.dll by using TlbImp.exe and making copy of it.

[Here is my connection class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw7ga.png)

Here is my main code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace RTEvents
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void connectionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connectivity con = new Connectivity();
            con.MdiParent = this;
            con.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            con.ControlBox = false;
            con.MaximizeBox = false;
            con.MinimizeBox = false;

            con.Text = "";
            con.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            con.Show();
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IsMdiContainer = true;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Checking device status...";

                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                    Connection con = new Connection();
                    RealTimeEvents rt = new RealTimeEvents();
                    if (con.CheckConnectivity(Connection.axCZKEM1))
                    {
                        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Device connected";

                        con.DeviceProcess(rt);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Device not connected";
                    }
                }).Start();

            }
            catch { }
        }

        public void setStatusLabel(string text)
        {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = text;
        }


    }
}
```

my connection class

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace RTEvents
{
    class Connection
    {
        public static string IP = "192.168.1.3";
        public static string PORT = "4370";
        public static string MACHINE_NUMBER = "1";
        public static string MASK = "65535";
        public static zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
        public static bool isConnected = false;
        public void DeviceProcess(RealTimeEvents rt)
        {

```
        if (Connection.axCZKEM1.RegEvent(Convert.ToInt32(MACHINE_NUMBER), Convert.ToInt32(MASK)))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
        {
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnFinger += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnFinger);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnVerify += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnFingerFeature += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerFeatureEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnFingerFeature);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFingerEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFingerEx);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnDeleteTemplate += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDeleteTemplateEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnDeleteTemplate);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnNewUser += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnNewUserEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnNewUser);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnHIDNum += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnHIDNumEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnHIDNum);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnAlarm += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAlarmEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnAlarm);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnDoor += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDoorEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnDoor);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnWriteCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnWriteCardEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnWriteCard);
            Connection.axCZKEM1.OnEmptyCard += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEmptyCardEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnEmptyCard);
            Connection.isConnected = true;
        }
    }
    public void UnProcessDevice(RealTimeEvents rt)
    {
        Connection.axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnFinger -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnFinger);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnVerify -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnVerifyEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnVerify);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnFingerFeature -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnFingerFeatureEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnFingerFeature);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnEnrollFingerEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEnrollFingerExEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnEnrollFingerEx);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnDeleteTemplate -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDeleteTemplateEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnDeleteTemplate);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnNewUser -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnNewUserEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnNewUser);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnHIDNum -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnHIDNumEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnHIDNum);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnAlarm -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAlarmEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnAlarm);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnDoor -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnDoorEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnDoor);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnWriteCard -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnWriteCardEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnWriteCard);
        Connection.axCZKEM1.OnEmptyCard -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnEmptyCardEventHandler(rt.axCZKEM1_OnEmptyCard);
        Connection.isConnected = false;
    }
    public bool CheckConnectivity(zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1)
    {
        if (isConnected == false)
        {

            if (axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IP, Convert.ToInt32(PORT)))
            {

                isConnected = true;
                return isConnected;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

that's the error and I've no clue how to solve it
[Thats the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2xsA.png)

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception is thrown when a class is constructed, cannot assign a particular static property.

See the documentation in MDSN;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx#Static

In your class you have;

```
public static zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass ... = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
```

Try removing this (for debugging purposes) and see if your exception is still thrown. If its not, then you know that this is the issue. As to the underlying issue as why, we will need more information about this zkemkeeper dll.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B15rs9I9HpmsMV9kMnRCLWJQc2c this is DLL is for 32 bit windows 7

http://www.zkteco.com/support/SDK/39_55.html (Stand Alone SDK)
u can get rest of dll from here.

Comment: I took a look at the this .dll and using dotpeek can see this is a COM interop class with a guid of 00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F. The constructor of the class uses MethodImpl (InternalClass and MethodCodeType.Type.Runtime attributes. I will try including this dll and trying it.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: we have to make copy of dll through tblimp,exe and we have also register all the dlls of that application. there is some flaw in companies dll

Comment: Thanks for your help